# How to transfer the clicked item in listview to editText in another activity in android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I want to get the item on list view to edit Text in another activity.
When clicked on list view item, I want to transfer the item in another activity in edit Text.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Any Ideas? Have you tried to put it in your Intent as Extra?

Answer (score 2):

You have to make onItemClickListner of listview like that.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("new_variable_name","value");
         startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Then in the new Activity, retrieve those values:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
```

`if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("new_variable_name");
}`

And finally set Value to editText like this

```
editText.setText(value);
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
lstView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("text", text want to transfer);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). And when you pass the content of the ListView to the next activity, you can use `editText.setText("Your Text")`.

You can also pass your data through intents from which you are calling your new activity.

Answer (score 0):

1. create `onClick` method like this.

   ```
   ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.newsList);
   list.setAdapter(adapter);

   list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long offset) {
           NewsItem item = (NewsItem) adapter.getItem(position);

           Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewsDetailsActivity.class);
           intent.putExtra(KEY, item.getHeadline());

           startActivity(intent); 
       }
   });
   ```
2. In next activity

   ```
   Intent intent = getIntent();
   headline = intent.getStringExtra(KEY);
   ```

have a look [here](http://javatechig.com/android/pass-a-data-from-one-activity-to-another-in-android)